# Terraform aws_route_table hierarchy of traffic direction

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm working on creating a route table for my AWS VPC.  I have three subnets:

1. authentication (public)
2. application (private)
3. internet egress (NAT instance)

I'm trying to create a terraform `resource "aws_route_table"` with those rules in mind for my private subnet.  However I don't want to direct traffic that came from the public subnet, back through the private so how do I ignore that?

Then I realized that I don't want to hijack s3 (any amazon service) traffic and do I have to be explicit about that?

```
resource "aws_route_table" "private_route_table" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"

  route {
    cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/24"
    # TODO: Ignore - Let it go local
  }

  # Do I need to worry about VPC Endpoints?
  route {
    cidr_block = "s3"
    aws_vpc_endpoint = "${aws_vpc_endpoint.s3.id}"
  }

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    instance_id = "${aws_instance.nat_instance.id}" 
  }
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Hi! Can you explain me more when you apply the Terraform configuration, what is the error. Or what do you got and what expected?

Comment: I can't really apply it, the third block to direct all traffic to the NAT works but the other two arn't supported by any documentation so it errors.  This is more of a conceptual question on networking in AWS with terraform, do I need to worry about local traffic or vpc endpoints?

Comment: Hi, if you are trying to protect your s3 buckets, don't create VPC endpoints, just restrict the access to specific roles and with specific actions. You need and EC2 in public subnets in order you to ssh to them. You can follow these recommended architectures scenarios: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenarios.html